# How to decode base64 and turn it back into an image in perl

Tags: perl, base64

I have a variable `$photo` (huge string that has been base64 encoded) that I believe I need to decode it using `MIME::Base64`
with something like this:

```
my $decoded= MIME::Base64::decode_base64($photo);
```

now after that how to I make $decoded back into a jpg as it was before?

Comment: After decoding, the content of `$decoded` should be valid jpg data, assuming that `$photo` contained a properly-Base64-encoded jpg image to start with. Are you asking how to write that data to a file? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: yes Im asking how to write that to a file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write it to a file just like you can write any other data. You need to set the [filehandle to binary](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html), though.

```
my $decoded= MIME::Base64::decode_base64($photo);
open my $fh, '>', 'photo.jpg' or die $!;
binmode $fh;
print $fh $decoded;
close $fh
```